# generate a lot of low resolution images from high-resolution images

Tags: python, image-processing

I need generate quite **a lot of** low-resolution (`64x64`) images (all with the same size) from one high-resolution (`256x256`) image in which each of the them is **different** from the others on per pixel basis.

I searched python library and didn't find the one I need. Do you have any idea to achieve this?

Comment: What does *"different in pixel"* mean? Are they JPEG or PNG images?

Comment: What is *"high resolution"*? What is *"low resolution"*?

Comment: What OS are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: "different in pixel" means that each low resolution is different from the others according to their pixels.For examples,different image resize algorithms will generate different low-res images in pixels.what I need is quite a lot of low-res images from one high-res image.And all my high-res images are JPG format.

Comment: Hi,Mark.I am using linux,high-res and low-res means the image size(or pixel size).For example,image of 256x256 to image of 64x64.

Comment: So you have one 256x256 JPEG and you want to resize it to 64x64 and then copy it 8,000 times and in each copy randomly change one pixel?

Comment: Emm...,it's right in some way.What exactly I want is more variation,not just one pixel.

Comment: 1. change resolution 2. add random noise to each low res copy.

Comment: What is the goal of this task? Do you want to compare specific algorithms?

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: @m7913d,I want to train a generative adversarial network of which the training dataset only contains some high-res images,so I need to use these images to generate a lot of low-res versions to be my training data.The requirement is to be more variations between the low-res images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that just at the command-line in `bash` with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

The easiest way to generate some variation is by varying the JPEG quality:

```
for ((quality=60;quality<=100;quality++)) ; do 
    convert StartImage.jpg -resize 64x64 -quality $quality q-$quality.jpg
done
```

So this will generate 41, low-res (64x64) images called `q-60.jpg`, `q-61.jpg` ... from one `StartImage.jpg`

You can generate a list of image filename and pixel hash (checksum) for each file like this in order to show that the pixel content varies between images:

```
identify -format "%f %#\n" q*jpg
```

**Sample Output**

```
q-100.jpg 2cf03ae65ee8b7720f4c395480043542b618c907929c219509c1f93a2352ae10
q-60.jpg d54d929aac414eaf73ee1589d8f5cf5341e03793fb99a71b9eef5b57297dcd4f
q-61.jpg 285ee9ac56b8508042a64d4ac2d1cd4d21edf5ea6ab9fe94ff423b2cb9ad8cf8
q-62.jpg a0c6175a6549c935c2ff0acd3efc0e27e2534622e1169be65bb39032c96b7e42
q-63.jpg efd2d677f05d99ac47a0696691cb5e8242e40bf2fcef6b690ccb3ec644aec191
q-64.jpg 084ec882abdf9c8218b28e91278f0266a83a7ce5865a48713fc84fd077405471
q-65.jpg 6c37565bb1648c2c4f1c30b4eac03c6580ec66a1bff641d0f9cf948e068238eb
q-66.jpg 52cca810bf79a146bebd55b5474e3d485fd4f29054cc3eafce61b4ae2f42450b
q-67.jpg 17c98b4b47a3c31cff61260e84bfc7cf5c8a4cf8168d393d43b3b431fedfbaaa
q-68.jpg dc2f6fef80ab42551db8d09758c8bc4dcd5990c07bcd397d27eae71a5665d3cb
q-69.jpg 6baac69324e2f2962e568b99f24a6d3e9e41048150f21f2c4deec81c08514df4
q-70.jpg d2046a958374766e13e27e1e9222628d31b4619ead1528e2d48a9e90952408a6
q-71.jpg afc5f08d957e145a832d97a1e6c6c22c853eea1adb02eb73536f0c8a8089b266
q-72.jpg 2b12320a71f5a90c812883146749dd226daae20ba67435cea23fd043b67238bd
q-73.jpg ceda0e3f19717a5dd34e96aec24a7b4c4019ec67b52db8752f72da6e1e1d14c5
q-74.jpg 7362211710ac5aa59886c1f7638a8e0b4f69d4a519d41c52ac762256ffce1d40
q-75.jpg bc884873fb928357db6cfcfe784df16fe7541caf2b611d461f9ffdc53ac02cbe
q-76.jpg 8f9b491ad579c0ea8af83119d97b1c6b121dff51ce8bb8483198259231836a30
q-77.jpg 72a3091d5b746d0277c3384e7078b9d834a0723344922c16a82a02a6e2cb4c0d
q-78.jpg 0cbc79f79c69faa95c4923f46c910545635d2e0330894e0549b18553c97ae424
q-79.jpg fcb1fa2dc81ca5c3f561cd12fd4b3e17d2bf1721f978429fbc4eebda5b6edc94
q-80.jpg 2c8bd5bb8aa9aa4490eb00ffb785dd73e0f620b9adbdb91a4c626c34fb0bcc16
q-81.jpg 7800ccecefc462d9a9ec44e39ccfc089e23072775cc8ff3d7ee3f37df118ea41
q-82.jpg c96fc0f19c8868555598e4a377b92fb7686e39f334126d5cf93f23b721e39745
q-83.jpg 837c1fef0758594f69f4da60583aa49b1ec2ca0b3c53a6a0d5d562ed91846d92
q-84.jpg eed3d7cdde44d4bc6ba30ac167765d266af4e5342a7e88e553cf3a8d2af94cd1
q-85.jpg 35a5da0a8b696fc1019dc43b029ba3a6fbaf3ddf800d82cc8e1c26ef41f525ea
q-86.jpg 2926a2b0a6a2e919005581250d5c59261c7dd9f4746c03a5aef7fdf385db321e
q-87.jpg 3ffc4e3bae6ce41e3c88637d60e551dc1727f113125281a996f5595408363f50
q-88.jpg 5141ae616bbf2d1e477263b949ec11f6a0c2a4eb4985e098bbc961b03ab848cb
q-89.jpg 70133a7eccd264bf4e51bbe7dfe96478c646f5009485b5f77939675205a552a6
q-90.jpg 046efec5e6c0b879c44951caf074625b24c82ec83b6fe0016a08a2acd3720907
q-91.jpg 0a60d8f0e7ac8dcfc5d410a15f502ba5b719cde5798eb2b84198169c56af5d32
q-92.jpg dee0d2c654a4aef65e49001153ccbd82600664e577648f3a5de0025f37d0452e
q-93.jpg 4cd8ffadf1d4de07678ba9360b5fcbd625812e0e81a7c6c9195dde3ea66d3605
q-94.jpg 8215938adf00b3d8ef102794b10fe2c5ae70e9784014f4d64f26b6636c779073
q-95.jpg e8700f07e76c90c30b4e610c9d93ec436a6d73e43269ca205008c77eed422c7d
q-96.jpg 284e5473ab979a9026a531d0b4af44b85f9a1f9c9d7468d76bc9c5da815f57e4
q-97.jpg 064a006b20e8e133da36442f5720adb2641dfd2da767fd1dadfbce26e3c341ab
q-98.jpg 4f2eb84b7b983dfbb01fca522c45afb13107519b61755e131128fda3e31919da
q-99.jpg 72780c21a4ec4fe00cc9f5e8685c8ea1f8045a5dd2d15dcadf0ce5fe381f4372
```

---

Other ways of making slight variations might be changing the contrast a little, blurring a little, sharpening a little. So, if you wanted thousands of variations, you could use nested loops something like this:

```
for blur in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do
   for contrast in a b c d ; do
      for quality in 61 62 63 .. 100 ; do
         convert StartImage.jpg -blur 0x$blur -contrast $contrast -quality $quality b${blur)-c${contrast}-q${quality}.jpg
      done
   done
done
```

---

As @spektre points out, another method would be to add random noise, which you could also do in ImageMagick, adding 0-39% of noise like this:

```
for ((noise=0;noise<40;noise++)) ; do
   convert StartImage -resize 64x64 \( +clone +noise random \) -compose blend -define compose:args=$noise -composite noise-$noise.jpg
done
```

Comment: Thank you Mark,I am not familiar with bash programming,is there any python or matlab version to achieve this ?BTW,what's the differences among the images q60.jpg,q61.jpg...?

Comment: Each one is created with a different quality setting, so the ones with lower quality are smaller and less accurate representations of the 64x64 image, while the ones nearer to `quality=100` are more accurate, faithful representations of the image but which require larger file sizes (in general). Try taking one of your images and saving it with quality 10... `convert someImage -quality 10 low-quality.jpg` and you will see it is a poor likeness.

Comment: If you tag your question with the `Matlab` tag, I guess some kind soul might do something similar for your in Matlab. You can do the above in Python, there are Python bindings for ImageMagick - just I don't speak Python. Try adding a `Python` tag too.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a try!And  does all the low-res images have the same spatial size,for example 64x64?

Comment: You can check the size like this `identify q*jpg` and you will see the width and height as `WxH`. The proportions of the images will be retained, so if you start with a square image, you will end up with a set of square images. If you start with a tall, narrow image, you will end up with all images being equally tall and narrow as each other  but to fit within 64x64. If you want to force 64x64 regardless of the start image proportions and cause shape distortion, change the command to `convert StartImage -resize 64x64\! -quality $quality q-$quality.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

The matlab version of Mark Setchell's answer:

```matlab
I = imread('your_image.jpg');
Ismall = imresize(I, [64 64]);
for i=0:10
  filename = ['output/', num2str(i), '.jpg']; % write to output folder
  imwrite(I, filename, 'Quality', i*10);
end
```

Reference:

- [`imwrite`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html)
- [`imresize`](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html)

Comment: Nice one, thank you.

Comment: Very useful !Thank you!@m7913d

Comment: @Mark Setchell,Thank you!